# How do I go to a particular number character in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I have an error in some code that specifies a specific character number as the issue (SQL code). How do I jump to a specific character number in emacs? Note that this is the character number, not line number. Presumably we are counting whitespace/newlines as characters. Right now I am manually doing binary search with what-cursor-position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `goto-char` should do what you are asking.  By default is is bound to <kbd>M-g</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>.

Comment: Although I'm not sure how it counts multi-byte characters, if that's important to you.

Comment: It counts *characters* rather than *bytes*.

Answer (score 0):

You can try <kbd>M-<</kbd> to get to the top, then <kbd>M-2</kbd><kbd>M-3</kbd> (the whole number) and finally <kbd>C-f</kbd> to move forward. The number can be entered with <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>, too.